# Отличие между сложными словами, выражающими подобие

Tags: лексика

Чем отличаются сложные слова, имеющие второй основой -видный (стекловидный) от слов, имеющих второй основой -образный (шарообразный, куполообразный)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничем не отличаются.Это  СУФФИКСОИДАЛЬНЫЕ СИНОНИМЫ со значением подобия.

Прилагательные в современном русском языке, образо­ванные при помощи суффиксоидов, -видный и -образный, составляют сино­нимические пары: крестовидный — крестообразный, клиновидный — клинообразный, конусовидный — конусообразный, кольцевидный — кольцеобразный.

Прилагательные, образованные при помощи вышеназванных суффиксоидов,
имеют общее словообразовательное значение **"похож на то, что названо 
производящей основой"**. Например, прилагательные клиновидный и клинообразный
выступают как синонимы в значении „имеющий вид, форму клина”. Ср.:
Шея [кабана] короткая и очень сильная; голова клиновидная (Арсеньев, По
Уссурийской тайге). Клинообразная русая борода удлиняла бледное, испи­
тое лицо (М. Горький, Тоска).

В современном русском языке наблюдаются случаи, когда прилагатель­ные с суффиксоидами **-образный, -видный** вступают в синонимические связи
с прилагательными, образованными при помощи суффиксов **-ист- или -чат-**.
**Тогда они имеют общее словообразовательное значение "похож на то, что
названо производящей основой"**: волнистый — волнообразный, игольчатый —
игловидный, чешуйчатый — чешуеобразный, гребенчатый — гребневидный и др.
Так, например, прилагательные волнистый и волнообразный синонимизиру­
ются в значении „похожий на волны” : Сквозь волнистые туманы пробирается
луна (Пушкин, Зимняя дорога). С полнеба покрывалось волнообразными,
легкими, как вата, облаками (Эртель, Записки степняка).

Прилагательные с компонентом **-видный** наиболее часто трактуются на основе семантического компонента **"похожий по виду"**. При сопоставлении объектов живой природы роль играет общий наружный вид предмета, который необязательно должен иметь определенную форму, при этом форма объектов не является основным свойством, основываясь на котором говорящий уподобляет сравниваемый объект эталонному, при уподоблении на первом плане оказываются несколько иные характеристики объектов: размер, цвет, издаваемые звуки, наличие или отсутствие шерсти, конечностей (мышевидный, медведеобразный, енотовидный, рыбообразный) и т.д.

Из списка слов с суффиксоидами  подобия должны быть исключены слова типа
*миловидный, очевидный, страхообразный, старообразный, шелковидный, 
корковидный и под.*, которые либо не реализуют идею уподобления вообще, либо 
объектом сравнения является не форма предмета, а какой-либо другой признак.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, предполагается ли, что подобие выражено на основании сходства формы? Только в случае описания объектов живой природы на первый план выступает не форма? Исключить из списка слов означает исключить из этого разряда? К какому же тогда разряду их причислить?

Comment: Подобие на основании сходства формы,внешнего вида, а вот если объект живой природы,то внешний вид тоже на первом плане, но, кроме него, имеется в виду весь образ, все качества. Медведеобразный - и внешне похож, и большой, и косолапый, и увалень, и пр. Енотовидный - и внешность енота, и все качества енота как вида. Миловидный - это не подобный милому, это у него милый вид. Видн(ый) - не суффиксоид,а  второй корень в сложном слове - два корня и соединительный гласный.Страхообразный - страшный образ, шелковидный - шёлковый вид, т.е. блестящий и мягкий, корковидный - не похож на корку, а высохший.